# Spring Security / Wordpress integration

Tags: wordpress, spring, security, model-view-controller, single-sign-on

I have a technical challenge that i need some help with. We're building a technical service for the web and Java and Spring are the tools we use. We also use Wordpress with a web store plugin (WooCommerce).

We need to find a way to integrate our Java web application and the Wordpress site. The major issue being user authentication. We use Spring security for the Java application and Wordpress has its own user management. The preferrable solution would be to have Wordpress be the master for user registration, maintenance and authentication.

Does anyone out there have experiences and/or ideas about how to solve this? Could you please share them here. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about implementing Single sign on between spring app and wordpress app?

Answer (score -1):

check [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) or [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home) as your Single Sign On System.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that for the future. We ended up dropping the Wordpress off-the-shelf web store in and implementing what we needed in the Java application, so i never had to solve the issue.